# How to add automatic description to all shapefiles from the folder name in Google Earth?

Tags: kml, google-earth, kmz

In Google Earth I have many folders containing many shapefiles, so I would like how to attribute automatically the folder name as a description for all these shapefiles?

Comment: Please I need help about my question

Comment: Sorry, but it is not clear to me what you are asking to do... what end result you want?  When you import a shapefile into Google Earth it gets converted to KML, which you appear to have arranged those into folders. Do you want to apply the folder names as descriptions in Earth? If so, at the shapefile level, or for each feature? Or, do you want to apply the folder names as attributes in the original shapefiles? That would be hard since there's no way to save shapefiles out of Google Earth.  Please clarify what end result you want so we can try to provide a better answer.